# How to send the ID to new page after insert?

Tags: apex, visualforce, insert, post

There are 2 pages.
I inserted one record into an object with the save button on page 1 and transitioning to page 2, Now I want to get the ID on page 2, what should I do?

ID was auto-numbered by object.
Here is my code.

```
    public class CustomerInfoController {
    
    public string name{get;set;}
    public string furigana{get;set;}
    public string tele{get;set;}
    public string mail{get;set;}
    public string post{get;set;}
    public string location{get;set;}
    public string location2{get;set;}
    
    public string apartment{get;set;}
    public string remarks{get;set;}
     
    public CustomerInfo__c customer{
    
    get{
            CustomerInfo__c customer = new CustomerInfo__c ();
            customer.Name__c = name;
            customer.furigana__c = furigana;
            customer.Contact_Time__c = string.join(selections,';');

            customer.Tele__c = tele;
            customer.Mail__c = mail;
            customer.Post__c = post;
            customer.Location__c = location;
            customer.Location2__c = location2;
            customer.Apartment__c = apartment;
            customer.Remarks__c = remarks;
            
            return customer;
    
    }
    set;
    
    }
    public List<String> selections = new List<String> {};
public List<String> getSelections() {
        return selections;
    }

public void setSelections(List<String> values) {
        this.selections = values;
    }
       public List<SelectOption> getOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new list<SelectOption>();
         Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = CustomerInfo__c.Contact_Time__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pickListEntry = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry pick: pickListEntry) {
            options.add(new selectOption(pick.getValue(), pick.getLabel()));
        }
        return options;
    }  
        public PageReference confirm(){
        return Page.registerConfirmPage;
        
        }
        
        public PageReference cancel(){
        return Page.registerPage2;
        
        }
        public PageReference saveCustomerInfo() {
            
            insert customer;
            PageReference redirect = Page.selectPayment;
            redirect.getParameters().put('id', customer.Id);
            system.debug('ID is:'+ customer.Id);
            return redirect;
        }
        public PageReference savecCredit() {
           system.debug('The ID is:' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
           return Page.thankyou;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saving the record, you pass the ID by a URL parameter:

```
insert record;
PageReference redirect = Page.page2;
redirect.getParameters().put('id', record.Id);
return redirect;
```

---

Your problem is that you're using a getter, so every time you access `customer`, you're creating a new instance of a `CustomerInfo__c` in memory. This means that:

```
insert customer;
System.debug(customer.id);
```

Is actually referring to two different objects, as well as the subsequent line where you try to assign the Id to the parameter. You can verify for yourself that they're two different objects:

```
System.assert(customer === customer); // assertion fails here
```

A single-line fix for this problem would look like this:

```
public PageReference saveCustomerInfo() {
  CustomerInfo__c customer = this.customer; // we create it once
  insert customer;
  PageReference redirect = Page.selectPayment;
  redirect.getParameters().put('id', customer.id);
  return redirect;
}
```

This solution takes advantage of [Name Shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm) to retain a local copy of the object the getter created. This is not particularly legible code, however.

I'd advise changing your controller code to:

```
public class CustomerInfoController {
    public CustomerInfoController() { // Initialize record
        customer = new CustomerInfo__c();
    }
    public CustomerInfo__c customer { get; set; }
    public PageReference confirm(){
        return Page.registerConfirmPage;
    }
    public PageReference cancel(){
        return Page.registerPage2;
    }
    public PageReference saveCustomerInfo() {
        insert customer;
        PageReference redirect = Page.selectPayment;
        redirect.getParameters().put('id', customer.Id);
        return redirect;
    }
    public PageReference savecCredit() {
        system.debug('The ID is:' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
        return Page.thankyou;
    }
}
```

And in your Visualforce markup, you can bind to the fields directly:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!customer.Name__c}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!customer.Furigana__c}" />
<!-- etc -->
```

If you're having field level security issues, you can still bind the values the way you are now, but you would want to construct the record immediately before inserting:

```
public class CustomerInfoController {
    public string name {get; set; }
    public string furigana {get; set; }
    public string tele {get; set; }
    public string mail {get; set; }
    public string post {get; set; }
    public string location {get; set; }
    public string location2 {get; set; }
    public string apartment {get; set; }
    public string remarks {get; set; }

    public PageReference confirm(){
        return Page.registerConfirmPage;
    }

    public PageReference cancel(){
        return Page.registerPage2;
    }

    public PageReference saveCustomerInfo() {
        CustomerInfo__c customer = new CustomerInfo__c (
            customer.Name__c = name,
            customer.furigana__c = furigana,
            customer.Tele__c = tele,
            customer.Mail__c = mail,
            customer.Post__c = post,
            customer.Location__c = location,
            customer.Location2__c = location2,
            customer.Apartment__c = apartment,
            customer.Remarks__c = remarks
        );
        insert customer;
        PageReference redirect = Page.selectPayment;
        redirect.getParameters().put('id', customer.Id);
        system.debug('ID is:'+ customer.Id);
        return redirect;
    }
    public PageReference savecCredit() {
        system.debug('The ID is:' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
        return Page.thankyou;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou!
By the way how can I show id in page2 or get it in the common controller?

Comment: @Kyori `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')` should do it.

Comment: @Kyori Interesting. I don't see any reason why Id should be null. Could you please edit your original question and include all the relevant code?

Comment: I added my code in the original question.Can you please check it for me?

Comment: @Kyori Your problem was that you were reinitializing the `customer` variable each time. I've added an explanation and two alternative fixes.

Comment: I got the Id by using way one.Thank you so much!